# Find the boundary condition of the nonlinear partial differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have first-order nonlinear partial differential equations
$$
\frac{du}{dt}+u\frac{du}{dx} =-u^3, u\Bigr|_{t=0}=f(x)
$$
solution 
$$
dt=\frac{dx}{u}=-\frac{du}{u^3}
$$
$$
F(x-\frac{1}{u},t-\frac{1}{2u^2})
$$
Need find boundary conditions f(x) (for example u(t=0,x)=x and find $u$)
But my simple function have a solution something like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=c1%3Dx-1%2Fx,c2%3D-1%2F(2x%5E2))
and $u$ have very bad solution($u\Bigr|_{t=0}=\frac{1}{x} $ is cheating ' $x-\frac{1}{u}=0$')

Comment: You have a partial differential equation, so you should also use partial derivatives by using \partial.

Comment: i don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the general solution of the PDE :
$$F\left(x-\frac{1}{u}\:,\:t-\frac{1}{2u^2}\right)=0$$
Don't forget $=0$ : Without $=0$ this is not an equation for the implicit solution.

So far the condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$ isn't taken into account. Deriving the function $F$ from this condition is puzzling if $f(x)$ is not written explicitely : This involves $f^{-1}$ i.e. the inverse function $f^{-1}\left(f(x)\right)=x$ . The calculus is shown in the attached sheet.

A more concrete exemple of this calculus is given below, in the case $f(x)=x$ :

Alternatively, the general solution of the PDE can be expressed on this implicit form :
$$x-\frac{1}{u}=\Phi\left( t-\frac{1}{2u^2}\right)$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function.

From the condition $u(x,0)=x \quad\to\quad x-\frac{1}{x}=\Phi\left( -\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)$

Lef $X=-\frac{1}{2x^2} \quad\to\quad x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2X}} \quad\to\quad \frac{1}{\sqrt{-2X}} -\sqrt{-2X} =\Phi\left( X\right)$

So, the function $\Phi$ is determined. Then :
$$\Phi\left( t-\frac{1}{2u^2}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-2 \left(t-\frac{1}{2u^2} \right) }} -\sqrt{-2\left(t-\frac{1}{2u^2} \right)}$$
The solution on implicit form is :
$$x-\frac{1}{u}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{u^2}-2t}} -\sqrt{\frac{1}{u^2}-2t}$$
Solving this equation for $u$ leads to the explicit solution $u(x)$. But this would be a too arduous task.

ATTACHMENT :

[image]

Note : in the particular case $f(x)=x \quad\to\quad f^{-1}(\chi)=\chi$ which leads to the same result as obtained above.